# Extremely short definite integral question here?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have to find the definite integral

$$\begin{split}
F(w) &= \int_0^\infty [e^{-at} e^{-jwt}]\,dt \\
     &= \int_0^\infty e^{-t[a+jw]}\,dt \\
     &= \frac{-1}{a+jw}
        \left. [e^{-(a+jw)t}] \right|_0^\infty.
\end{split}
$$

Problem is,I dont know how to solve it from here.Can you do this for me?

I know that the answer should be $F(w)=1/(a+jw)$

Answer (score 2):

Well, at $t=0$, the exponent becomes $1$, and at $t \to \infty$, the exponent tends to $e^{-kt} \to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

One also should add that $|e^{j\omega t}|=1$ and therefore $\lim_{t\to\infty} e^{-(a - j\omega) t} = 0 $ provided $a>0$ and $\omega\in \mathbb R$.